# How to abstract parts of a method into "sub-methods" (Python)

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm working my way through SICP, and have been reading Code Complete a bit. In Code Complete, I learnt to abstract and structure things as much as possible. In SICP, I learnt to create "helper" functions for every task that could possibly be abstracted into one. Anyway, my problem: I have a class "A", that should be able to do task "b", task "c", and task "d". So I create 3 methods, "b", "c", and "d". The tasks that each of those methods have to do are reasonably complex, but fit with the level of abstraction my class and other code provides(e.g. the class abstracts database access, and rather than having `A.findEmployee('Steve')` return a list or other low-level data-type, it returns an Employee instance). The findEmployee method can (and should, in my opinion) be divided in different parts as well. It could for example call two functions, `fetchEmployeeData('Steve')`, and `returnEmployeeInstance(employeedata)`.
But just putting all those functions in a class, like this:

```
class EmployeeDB(object):
  def findEmployee(self,name):
    employeedata=self._fetchEmployeeData(name)
    employeeinstance=self._returnEmployeeInstance(employeedata)
    return employeeinstance
  def _fetchEmployeeData(self,name):
    pass
  def _returnEmployeeInstance(self,employeedata):
    pass
```

makes it much less structured, and doesn't really help improve cohesion.
What is an appropriate way to structure my code, in cases such as this?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I just realised I could do it like this:

```
class EmployeeDB(object):
  def findEmployee(self,name):
    def fetchEmployeeData(name):
      pass
    def returnEmployeeInstance(employeedata):
      pass

    employeedata=fetchEmployeeData(name)
    employeeinstance=returnEmployeeInstance(employeedata)
    return employeeinstance
```

It hides the sub-functions nicely, and looks rather nice, but I only very seldom see this in any code, so I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. What do you think?

Comment: this is not good. You use inner functions where them are not needed. they be declared Each time `findEmloyee` method will be run.

Comment: I would recomend You To have at least two classes One for data manipulation and other Employee class. You can have third one as Employee manager.

Comment: I'd suggest using the first variant, defining functions in the class with a leading underscore. Defining functions inside of another function is normally only done if you need the closure, or if it's a helper function that won't ever be used in any other part of your class. It makes OOP / subclassing / monkeypatching impossible as you can't access the nested functions from outside, and could lead to code duplication - e.g. if you want to add a method `getAllEmployees` you could just define `_fetchAllEmployees` and then reuse `_returnEmployeeInstance` for the results.

Comment: @oleg:Then, I'd have one class of which the only purpose is to contain helper-functions for another class. That doesn't sound very pretty, or logical...

Comment: @l4mpi: "you can't access the nested functions from outside". Isn't that pretty much the idea of data hiding and black-box abstractions?  McConnell seems to be very convinced that it is important to hide as much of the inner workings of an abstraction as possible. This way, he argues, every abstraction can be a black-box abstraction, so you can forget about the inner workings of the abstraction(or at least, that's what I understood).

Comment: Hard to say much definite without seeing the code, but if `findEmployee()` literally does nothing except call those two functions, why not call `_fetchEmployeeData()` at the beginning, and then have the body of `_returnEmployeeInstance()` as the rest of the body of `findEmployee()` instead?

Comment: In other words, if `_returnEmployeeInstance()` always requires some employee data, than that function could call `_fetchEmployeeData()` instead of `findEmployee()` calling it. Then, `findEmployee()` would do nothing except call `_returnEmployeeInstance()`, and you could remove it, and just rename `_returnEmployeeInstance()` to `findEmployee()`. If you end up with a function that literally does nothing except call other ones, and does nothing on its own account, you've probably abstracted it one level too far.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths:The whole Employee thing is just an example. I encountered this problem on a specific piece of code, but the question really is about these kinds of situations in general. Normally, Normally, I"d do something like that, but it makes the code complex, and it's pretty much the opposite of what SICP tries to teach me:that each task that can be abstracted(i.e. when you could give a name to a task that is different from the name of the method it is in), should be abstracted.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me, and I don't want to look like someone who asks, but thinks he already knows everything(which I can assure you, I absolutely don't). I'm just trying to bring things I've read and practiced in famous, critically acclaimed programming books into practice with Python, and I'm having some trouble with that. Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: @Taoelism: I'd make the same point, if each function should do one thing, and do one thing well, then if you reach the point where you have a function that actually doesn't do anything at all by itself, then you've probably gone too far. Also - to reuse this example - if `_returnEmployeeInstance()` *always* needs employee data, then your functions are too highly coupled, because `findEmployee()` needs to know how `_returnEmployeeInstance()` works, because it needs to fetch employee data for it. If `_returnEmployeeInstance()` fetched that data, the enclosing function wouldn't need to know.

Comment: After all, the purpose of `findEmployee()` seems to be to return an employee instance based on the `name` passed to it, so if you find yourself declaring a function called `_returnEmployeeInstance()` which effectively does what `findEmployee()` is supposed to do, then you're probably introducing complexity, not removing it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths:This is my actual code: http://pastebin.com/4AKg7yr6 . The code adds JSON data to a MongoDB database. I've created a seperate method, "_returnmongoimplementations", that is(or rather, should be) part of the "_add" method, and I foresee needing more of those. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongo, but what you've done there seems fine to me from this perspective, since your `_add()` method does real stuff, and it seems like making a list you need is a reasonable thing to break out into a separate procedure. If you're going to "need more of those kind of methods" in that particular place, then maybe there's an opportunity to make a new class for this purpose, if they're all going to be doing something almost, but not quite, the same, but I think that question is very application-design-specific. If you have a lot of stuff to do, the code has to go somewhere.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths:Ok. Thank you for your help. I'll do that.

Comment: Also, your `_returnmongoimplementations()` method doesn't seem to access its `self` parameter, so it may well belong outside the class. Have you been running pylint on this stuff?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths:My IDE implements PyLint, so yeah. Do you mean that _returnmongoimplementations() doesn't use the self-argument, and hence should be a function rather than a method?

Comment: @Taoelism: Exactly, yes. If an instance method doesn't actually access any instance data, then in general it probably shouldn't be an instance method. Logically it may belong as a `@staticmethod` if it's really of no use other than for this particular class, or as a standalone function in some kind of separate mongo module. Pylint ought to give you a lot of hints about methods belonging as functions, too many instance attributes, and the like, which are helpful for suggesting possible refactors specific to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is that you don't need to repeat (parts of) the class name in its methods, because when possible you will no be able to employ duck typing.

So you will want to create methods of EmployeeDB without the "Employee"-prefix: find(), fetch() and returnInstance()

Using closures is good only when you really need to expand the scope of the function, and when that function will not be used by other methods. I find closures handy when I want to return function.

I think that you will find that using closures generally decreases code reuse("Don't repeat yourself").